# Adding new endpoint to FastAPI at runtime

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, openapi

I have a API Gateway service based on FastAPI and some specific services (like plugins) to connect with it. One of them - Auth service dealing with user accounts and access-tokens.
For example Auth service wants to tell AG about new functionality he provides and to register new endpoint in AG at runtime.

I see the following steps:

1. Auth creates new endpoint in AG, `/new_endpoint` for example;
2. All the traffic going to `http://AG/new_endpoint` will be redirected to `http://Auth/...`

I looked at the method `FastAPI.add_api_route` to add new endpoint. It works at runtime - I checked using curl.

There is no effect after refreshing `http://AG/docs` page because OpenAPI schema is cached.
I would like to re-generate OpenAPI schema and see `/new_endpoint` on the OpenAPI page.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution how to re-generate OpenAPI schema.

1. Drop cache `app.openapi_schema = None`
2. Re-generate schema `app.setup()`

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class NewEndpointResponse(BaseModel):
    status: str
    method: str
    url_path: str


async def catch_all(request: Request) -> JSONResponse:
    """
    Your new endpoint handler
    """
    # some logic to interact with Auth-service
    # like: requests.get("http://Auth/...")
    res = NewEndpointResponse(status="OK", method=request.method, url_path=request.url.path)
    return JSONResponse(res.dict(), status_code=200)


class EndpointRegisterDTO(BaseModel):
    endpoint: str = "/new_endpoint"
    method: str = "GET"
    name: str = "Extra Functionality"


@app.post("/register/endpoint")
async def add_endpoint(request: EndpointRegisterDTO):
    """
    Adds new endpoint at runtime
    """
    app.add_api_route(
        request.endpoint,
        catch_all,
        methods=[request.method],
        name=request.name,
        response_model=NewEndpointResponse)
    app.openapi_schema = None
    app.setup()
    return {"status": "OK"}
```

1. Open `http://AG/docs`. Only one endpoint is available.
2. Press "Try it out" and do `POST /register/endpoint` with suggested parameters.
3. Refresh `http://AG/docs` - now you can see `/new_endpoint`.
4. Call `GET /new_endpoint` and check that response is correct.

The solution is ugly a bit, but it works!
I think it's bloody hard to debug it!